# Inside the Node script - npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-start, react-scripts

I have very interesting problem. I have node + react script. Example folders in below;

```
/client(React is here)
...some react folders + files
...package.json
/models
/routes
/package.json
```

When i try the **create-react-app client** in different folder "**npm start**" works correctly, but when i create react inside the node script **npm start** command gives error.

[image: Screenshot of errors]

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

package.json(node)

```
{
  "name": "nodesrv",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"cd client && npm start\"",
    "start2": "node server.js",
    "start": "cd client && npm install && npm run build",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "emailjs": "^2.2.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "is-empty": "^1.2.0",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "mysql2": "^1.6.5",
    "next": "^8.1.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.1.1",
    "pg": "^7.11.0",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "rotating-file-stream": "^1.4.1",
    "sequelize": "^5.8.5",
    "validator": "^10.11.0",
    "winston": "^3.2.1"
  }
}
```

package.json (react)

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

[image: File & Folder structure]

Comment: please share your node script here

Comment: is it important? because i run npm-start command in client folder already. @MurtazaHussain

Comment: there is no build script in node package json.  `"cd client && npm install && npm run build"`

Comment: yes but problem is different :) It gives error only client. When i inside client folder. I try to npm-start (inside client folder) it gives error.

Comment: thats because there is not client folder inside client.. change your script to `npm install && npm run build"` and then run `npm start` inside client it will work

Comment: It may also help to know what the current working directory is when you run whatever you run that produces this error.

Comment: @ctt normally my client folder works single. but when i create new react script inside my script it gives error.

Comment: here is my file/folder structure https://i.imgur.com/NrO5Q88.jpg

Comment: Probable node version mismatch with dependencies! try to downgrade it.